# iOS Push notifications certificate switching in TestFlight

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications

In the good old days of the original TestFlight I had a development certificate set for TestFlight releases and a production certificate for the live release of an app I'm working on. Never had any problems.

Since Apple took over I noticed the push notifications were failing and I discovered that the TestFlight sandbox on Apple only worked with the production certificate. This made no sense but worked. A week ago the notifications started failing once again (invalid token 8). Shifting to the development certificate did the job (the way it should have originally been on the TestFlight sandbox).

This morning the notifications are failing again and once again moving to the production certificate sent all the notifications.

Now to my question, is Apple making some changes that are affecting this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For users having the same issue. After some investigation I noticed that running an app from Xcode signs the app with a development certificate but installing the same release off Apple TestFlight does so with a production certificate. The notifications would fail on my device since I still had the Xcode version installed rather than the TestFlight release. For some reason I never installed the final version through TestFlight but left the one deployed from Xcode.